# Strapi filtering that exclude relations

Tags: postman, strapi

I've got a relation 1 to many, but that many may not have relations, i want to filter all data that have not any relations.
Ive got a table circuits that can have many points. and i want to get every point that dont have any relation with circuits.
What im trying to do is first populate the data and then filter where the relation is null. i only got an error.

/api/points?populate=*&filters[circuit][$eq]=null

```
"data": null,
"error": {
    "status": 500,
    "name": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.